# Why is 'this' not taking on the correct scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Okay, I know there are some thousand odd threads about the scope of `this` in Javascript (which makes one wonder if the language was well designed) - but I still can't explain 'this' one:

```
//works
function Cat() { 
 this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
 function meow() {alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }; 
 this.meow = meow }
}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow() 

//works
function Cat() { 
this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
function meow() {alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }; 
this.meow = function() { alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }
}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow() 

//works
function Cat() { 
this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
function meow() {alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }; 
Cat.prototype.meow = function() { alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }
}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow() 

//doesn't work
function Cat() { 
this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
function meow() {alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }; 
this.meow = function() { meow() } }
}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow() 

//doesn't work
function Cat() { 
this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
function meow() {alert(this.theCatName + " meow") }; 
Cat.prototype.meow = function() { meow() } }
}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow()
```

Now my understanding is that in the later two cases the `Cat.prototype.meow` or `this.meow` are anonymous functions that happen to call meow(), which is an internal function of `Cat()` - but the context of `this` clearly refers to cat inside the function - What happens to it?

Here is a semi-canonical answer: 
[See How to access the correct this / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)
But it only has the following to say about what the context of 'this' actually is:

> this (aka "the context") is a special keyword inside each function and
>   its value only depends on how the function was called, not
>   how/when/where it was defined. It is not affected by lexical scope,
>   like other variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method of an object it only works if you call it as a member of the object, if you get the reference to the function or call it as a regular function, the context isn't the object. It's only how you call the function that decides the context, the context isn't inherited so if you call a function from a method it's just a regular function call.

Example:

```
function Dog() {

  function bark() {}
  this.bark = bark;

  this.barkThrice() {
    bark(); // function call; context = window
    this.bark(); // method call; context = the object
    var b = this.bark;
    b(); // function call; context = window
  }

}
```

To call the function as a method of the object you need to use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (or `bind` or `apply`) to set the context of the call:

```
function Cat() { 
  this.theCatName = "Mistigri"; 
  function meow() { alert(this.theCatName + " meow"); } 
  this.meow = function() { meow.call(this); };
}
var MyCat = new Cat();
MyCat.meow();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k6W9K/

Comment: Edit: I understand how to fix it, but I don't understand what's actually happening to the context of 'this'. meow() is a function of Cat(), being called by another function of Cat() both of which have this.theCatName in their context? So what is 'this' trying to reference when it cannot find theCatName ?

Comment: @user3467349: The function `meow` is not a member of the object, it's a function inside the `Cat` function. Javascript doesn't have a class scope, where everything in it is part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help a bit: 
A variable declared within a function is not accessible outside of that function.
A variable defined within a function is accessible to its nested functions.

```
function Cat() {

    // public var exist on the Cat instance: accesible from outside the Cat constructor
    this.theCatName = "Mistigri";

    // public function exist on the Cat instance
    // has access to all variables defined in the Cat constructor (_theCateName and _meow)
    // and all variables and methods defined on 'this'
    // this reference to a Cat Instance
    this.meow = function() {
        alert(this.theCatName);
        _meow();
    }

    // private var only accessible within the Cat constructor.
    var _theCateName = "_Mistigri"

    // private function only accessible within the Cat constructor.
    function _meow() {
        // _meow is defined as closure in the Cat constructor
        // In the function _meow 'this' is a reference to the scope from where the Cat function / constructor was applied (the window object in this case)

        alert(this.theCatName + " meow " + _theCateName); // outputs: undefined meow _Mistigri
    };

}
var MyCat = new Cat()
MyCat.meow()

alert (MyCat.theCatName)// outouts: Mistigri
```